# Data is accessible in HTML, but not in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to access the 'data' element in a JSON object. The element is accessible when called from HTML, but not accessible when called in JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<p>{{geoJson.data}}</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
let scope;
let datasources;
let attributeService;
let geofences = [];
let geoJson = [];

self.onInit = function() {
    scope = self.ctx.$scope;
    datasources = self.ctx.datasources;

    for (var i = 0; i < datasources.length - 1; i++) {
        geoJson.push(self.ctx.data[i]);
    }
    scope.geoJson = geoJson[0];
}
```

I expect the code to work when I call in JavaScript `geoJson[0].data`. However, this call is returning undefined.

Comment: check in console, after pushing in for loop what you are getting? try  geoJson.data.push(self.ctx.data[i]); then console it and check again, it should work

Comment: Since you miss some important context: Is the `onInit()` function called at all?

Comment: Why does the `for` loop use `i < datasources.length - 1`? Is it your intention to omit the last item?

Answer (score 0):

Try to console log scope.geoJson and see if you get the pushed elements.

```
//scope.geoJson = geoJson[0];    
console.log(scope.geoJson);
```